# "The data area passed to a system call is too small" when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a code which works good in all browsers, except IE (IE11 if it matters).

This code just loads a png image on a client. When I try to do it in IE, I get this error message:

> The data area passed to a system call is too small

Is there any workaround and how can I fix it?

```js
var link = document.getElementById("export-png");
link.href = "data:image/png;base64,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";
link.click();
```

```html
<a href="" id="export-png">To be clicked</a>
```

Comment: by `...` I mean some function, which crops a canvas and returns this -  `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")`.

Comment: Please click `<>` and post a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe you should show all the code.

Comment: Well, not **all** of it, just an MCVE of it.

Comment: In a minute. I will log the result from my cropping function.

Comment: Lol. _By ... I mean some possibly huge function that may give the error I see but I won't post here_

Comment: @mplungjan. Funny, but not right

Comment: I made a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Please, have a look.

Comment: I fixed your mcve and I see Edge dislikes the data protocol in the href

Comment: Thanks,  mplungjan!

Comment: I can't even test in IE11 - it does not like the snippet NOR the code in a jsfiddle. Saving the code into a file gives `The webpage cannot be displayed
 
   
 
    
Most likely cause:
•Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed.
 
`